# NSDictionary WriteToFile fails

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I can't work out why it keeps failing. It returns `NO`. I have searched this all afternoon, but nothing explains why or how to fix. Calling `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] isWritableFileAtPath:]` returns `NO`, which leads me to believe that the existing plist file can not be overwritten, but I can't work out how to change this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write ONLY files in Documents directory. But your plist file is not there

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: This is not 100% true, as you can also write into your ApplicationSupport folder.